# an operating system wasn't found try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, window

I reserved window 10 and i got it. After i got it got a problem the startmenu doesn't come out. So i use other way such as reset and i press keep my files... When at 66% its say fail. And i accidentally shut down... and after i open i get this "**an operating system wasn't found try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system press alt+ctrl+del**" just this message... please help THAT IS RESERVED NO CD............ i really need help. I am just 15 years old, i cant lost my main pc... :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason the install says, "Don't turn off or restart during install process..."

**Reinstall Original OS** 

The easiest way is going to be reinstalling the operating system. If you want to try and save your data, try partitioning your drive and install the original OS on the new partition. Then migrate your old data to the new install.

**Contact Microsoft Help Center**

Here is a link to get the Windows 10 (technical preview) ISO:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-download?ocid=tp_site_downloadpage

Log in with your microsoft credentials that you used when upgrading.

Comment: I suspect you wouldn't have seen this question if the OP had enough knowledge for this answer to be helpful, and then it would be helpful only in the sense of confirming one approach over another.

Comment: I just installed in a usb drive ... what to do next?